# How to do preloading in polymer for example hover images?

Tags: polymer

Does this preload my images to do hover stuff by changing the src "home/1.png" to "home/1b.png" in javascript or is there a better way to preload does things?

```
<section unresolved>
        <img hidden src="home/1b.png">
        <img hidden src="home/2b.png">
        <img hidden src="home/3b.png">
        <img hidden src="home/4b.png">
        <img hidden src="home/5b.png">
        <img hidden src="home/6b.png">
        <img hidden src="home/7b.png">
        <img hidden src="home/8b.png">
        <img hidden src="home/9b.png">

        <img src="home/1.png">
        <img src="home/2.png">
        <img src="home/3.png">
        <img src="home/4.png">
        <img src="home/5.png">
        <img src="home/6.png">
        <img src="home/7.png">
        <img src="home/8.png">
        <img src="home/9.png">
</section>
```

Comment: that seems like it should load your images. is it not working?

Comment: It is but maybe there is some special attribute instead of hidden I don't know about that does some fancy caching?

Comment: O by the way, Robdodson I need you please for some mayer performance issue on polymer bindings I want to show in a example but on github it takes ages for a response sometimes :) Also have no idea which part is responsible I can only show you the result.

Comment: If you don't want the images in markup you could load them in JavaScript, otherwise I don't know of any special way to do fancy caching beyond what the browser already does.

If you are having performance issues with databindings, create a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/nadiwo/1/edit) and share it on StackOverflow

Comment: created a example and a issue :) https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/760 is there somebody on irc I can talk to directly to explain the problem better?